# How to deploy Laravel + Vue.js project to live server?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment, server, liveserver

So, I'm currently working on an e-commerce web app which is based on Laravel + Vue.js and I've separated the project into 2 folders. One folder called "backend" contains the Laravel files and another called "frontend" contains the Vue.js files. To get the web app running locally, I have to run "php artisan serve" in the "backend" folder and "npm run dev" in the "frontend" folder. My question is, how does it work if I want to deploy these two folders in live server such as Plesk or cPanel?

I thought of just uploading those two folders in the live server and expect them to work just like a normal PHP-based project. But I think it doesn't work like that.

Comment: You need to configure the server to serve the files properly too. Or ship your frontend to Netlify/Vercel (example) and your backend to Heroku/Fly/Render. Otherwise, a docker container is still the easiest + most flexible way to go!